# ActiveMQ Artemis how to filter message by part of the "text" field

Tags: activemq-artemis, jolokia

Is there any way to filter messages in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.0 by part of the "text" field using the management console?
I use method "browse(java.lang.String)" and try to filter my message (example below) by this expression:

```
text LIKE '%777-555-333-111%'
```

Message example:

```
        {
            "address": "ADDRESS.EXAMPLE",
            "ShortProperties": {},
            "messageID": "11111",
            "priority": 4,
            "type": 3,
            "redelivered": false,
            "ByteProperties": {
                "_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE": 1
            },
            "IntProperties": {
                "CamelHttpResponseCode": 200
            },
            "durable": true,
            "StringProperties": {
                "Server": "nginx\/1.19.5",
                "CamelHttpCharacterEncoding": "UTF-8",
                "Content_HYPHEN_Type": "application\/xop+xml",
                "connection": "keep-alive"
            },
            "DoubleProperties": {},
            "expiration": 0,
            "text": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><processId>777-555-333-111<\/processId><\/error>",
            "BooleanProperties": {},
            "FloatProperties": {}
        }
```

However, it doesn't give me any results.
Would be grateful for a hint if it possible on my current Artemis version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter used by the `browse` management operation (as well as that used by JMS consumers, etc.) only applies to message *headers* and *properties*. You can't filter a message by the text in its body.

The data that you pasted is just the serialized message data sent to the client *after* the filter has already been applied.

Answer (score 0):

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis also supports special XPath filters which operate on
the body of a message. The body must be XML, see the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/filter-expressions#xpath) for further details.

To use an XPath filter use this syntax:

```
XPATH '<xpath-expression>'
```